# How to get the value of a selected radio button and checkbox using its class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I have a laravel form which uses a JSON object as it's source for questions and answer choices. This form allows for text answers, radio buttons and checkboxes. Upon submission, I use jQuery to obtain the value of all the responses which have a class=>response. Those responses/answers are then appended to a hidden textarea field.
I am able to retrieve all the text type responses correctly, however the radio and checkbox responses are incorrect. Instead of capturing the actual radio/checkbox selected, I am returning the final JSON index value from each radio/checkbox. For example, if there are 3 radio button options for a question, the value returned for the answer selected is '2' even if '0' was chosen.  How do I get the actual radio button/checkbox value clicked? It'd be great if I could actually store the text value of each index instead of the index number checked.

I included the jQuery first, then followed it with the portion of the form.

```
 /*Script for collecting all patient data; script for collecting questionnaire answers and submitting as JSON string*/
$("#formq").submit(function(){    
    $("#formq").append("<textarea name='answers' id='answers' hidden='hidden'></textarea>");
    var answers = new Object();
    $(".response").each(function(){
        answers[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
//Change answers object into json string; place answers into textarea and submit form
    $("#answers").text(JSON.stringify(answers)); 

<div class="form-group">
     @foreach($jsonObject['questions']['english'] as $key =>$question)   
       {{ Form::label('questions', $question['question'], array('class' => 'col-sm-9 display-label')) }}
         @if(($jsonObject['question_metadata'][$key]['multi_value']) == false)
           @if(($jsonObject['question_metadata'][$key]['text_value']) == true)                           
              <div class="col-sm-8" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">                                
                  {{ Form::text($key, null, array('class' => 'form-control response')) }}     
              </div>
           @elseif(($jsonObject['question_metadata'][$key]['text_value']) == false) 
              <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-right: 15px">
                  @foreach($question['choices'] as $key2 => $choice)
                    <div class="col-sm-9 radio" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                       {{ Form::radio($key, $key2, null, array('class' => 'response')) }} {{$choice}}
                   </div>                   
                  @endforeach 
              </div> 
           @endif
        @elseif(($jsonObject['question_metadata'][$key]['multi_value']) == true)                           
           <div class="col-sm-9" style="padding-right: 15px">
              @foreach($question['choices'] as $key3 => $choice)
                <div class="col-sm-9 checkbox" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                  {{ Form::checkbox($key, $key3, null, array('class' => 'response')) }} {{ $choice }}
                </div>
              @endforeach 
           </div>        
        @endif
   @endforeach
```

```
JSON snippet
{
  "questions": {
    "english": [
    {
        "question": "5. This question will provide a text box:"
    },
  {
    "question": "6. Another text box question:"
  },
  {
    "question": "7. This question will provide checkboxes so multiple items can be chosen:",
    "choices": {
      "0": "Option1",
      "1": "Option 2",
      "2": "Option 3",
      "3": "Option 4",
      "4": "Option 5",
      "5": "Option 6",
      "6": "Other"
    }
  },
  {
    "question": "8. This question will provide radio buttons:",
    "choices": {
      "0": "No",
      "1": "Yes"
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you check my below answer?

Comment: So sorry for the delay in response. The solution below did not work. When looking at the JSON string it returns, the questions which involve radio or checkboxes now return all the index values of the question. Here is a snippet of what I return. If you look at index 16 you will see zero followed by ','  & then additional index numbers and 17 shows both index numbers, 18 shows all four index numbers.   { "14":"my dog and hamster and all my books are meaningful to me","15":"remember","16":"0, 123456","17":"01","18":"0123","19":"01","20":"01","21":"","22":"","23":"0","24":"0","25":"0","26":"0""}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your jQuery code as below which is simply assigning the value if the element is textbox otherwise checked or not for radio and checkboxes.

```
var answers = new Object();
$(".response").each(function(){
   if($(this).is('[type="text"]') || $(this).is(':checked')) {
      answers[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
   }
});
```

The above code will replace the previous value when multiple checkboxes selected, so you can check if value exists for checkbox and append the value as comma `(,)` separated as below.

```
var answers = new Object();
$(".response").each(function(){
   if($(this).is('[type="text"]') || $(this).is(':checked')) {
      if(answers[$(this).attr('name')]) {
         answers[$(this).attr('name')] += ', ';
      } else {
         answers[$(this).attr('name')] = '';
      }

      answers[$(this).attr('name')] += $(this).val();
   }
});
```